# How to concatenate differents values for one keys

Tags: ruby

I have a trouble for several days and I need help to solve it. 
I have an hash with multiple values for the same key :

```
{"answers":
  [
    {"id":1,"value":true},
    {"id":3,"value":false},
    {"id":2,"value":3},
    {"id":1,"value":false},
    {"id":2,"value":false},
    {"id":2,"value":1}
  ]
}
```

I want a method to group all the values for one key, as an exemple :

```
{
  "answers": [
    {
      "id":1, "value": [true, false]    
    },  
    {
      "id":3, "value": [false]
    },
    {
      "id":2, "value":[3, false, 1]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried with the reduce method, but I cant find a way to link values to keys. 
Anyone can help me with that ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Its the same, didnt wanted to wrote it down, but I'll update it.

Comment: It should be ok now. Sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: "I cant find a way" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I cant find a way" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Hello @JörgWMittag. I feel a bit weird about your comments. For two reasons, the first one, I'm a beginner on Ruby On Rails and as a beginner, I don't know everything about method and any others stuff who can help me achieve what i'm looking for.
Secondly, I'm not asking for answers, I'm just looking for advices on how I could achieve my purpose and what is the best way to do it, that's why I wrote down the input and the output. (Because as I can see, there're a lot of way to achieve it). 
But I'll write a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash = {
  answers: [
    { id: 1, value: true },
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: 3 },
    { id: 2, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: 1 },
    { id: 3, value: false }
  ]
}

def doit(answers)
  answers.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    h.update(g[:id]=>{ id: g[:id], value: [g[:value]] }) do |_,o,n|
      { id: o[:id], value: o[:value]+n[:value] }
    end
  end.values
end

{ answers: doit(hash[:answers]) }
    #=> {:answers=>[
    #      {:id=>1, :value=>[true, false]},
    #      {:id=>2, :value=>[3, false, 1]},
    #      {:id=>3, :value=>[false]}
    #    ]
    #   }
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. That block is

```
do |_k,o,n|
  { id: o[:id], value: o[:value]+n[:value] }
end
```

See the doc for `update` for definitions of the three block variables, `_k`, `o` and `n`. I've written the first block variable (the common key) `_k`, rather than `k`, to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.

Note that before `values` is executed in `doit` the method has constructed the following hash.

```
{1=>{:id=>1, :value=>[true, false]},
 2=>{:id=>2, :value=>[3, false, 1]},
 3=>{:id=>3, :value=>[false]}}
```

Comment: Hello @CarySwoveland, I've made a mistake by saying "method", i'm really sorry about that. 
What if i want my output without method ? Should I take your block and convert it ? I have this error when I run `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. Any idea ?

Comment: I'll reply in (my) morning.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarySwoveland.

Comment: It works  and I have your last output in your solution. However, what should I do to getting my ouput ? When I tried this `polls = { polls: hash[:polls] }` it returns me this error `: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to regroup the array of hashes by the `:id` key in each hash.

This method takes the answers array and returns a new, transformed answers array:

```
def transform_answers(answers)
  answers
    .group_by { |h| h[:id] }
    .each_value { |a| a.map! { |h| h[:value] } }
    .map { |id, value| { id: id, value: value } }
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
hash = {
  answers: [
    { id: 1, value: true },
    { id: 1, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: 3 },
    { id: 2, value: false },
    { id: 2, value: 1 },
    { id: 3, value: false }
  ]
}

transformed_answers = transform_answers(hash[:answers]) # => [{:id=>1, :value=>[true, false]}, {:id=>2, :value=>[3, false, 1]}, {:id=>3, :value=>[false]}]
```

You can easily take the transformed answers and put them back into a hash resembling the original input:

```
transformed_hash = { answers: transformed_answers }
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann That would work too (thanks to the `Array#map!`)!

Comment: @StefanPochmann I decided to use your suggestion for the overall solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Heh :-). I also liked your other "for older Rubies" solution, it's what I had written myself. But it didn't look as nice, was nested a bit too deeply.

Comment: I've come to feel like that syntax causes more problems than it solves, but I know it's the dominant standard so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Consider using [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), which made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I had Hash#transform_values! in the original solution, but it does make it incompatible with older Rubies, so I had to have an alternative solution in there. I actually think Hash#each_value is a better fit here since we're mutating the arrays created by Enumerable#group_by, and as a bonus it's backwards-compatible.

Comment: @mwp And it's shorter :-)

Comment: @stefanPochmann  Hello guys and thanks a lot for your answers. I'm currently trying all of yours, and to be honest, I'm learning a lot from them, thanks.
I've made a mistake by saying method because i do not need it in fact, french habits. But I'll do my best to convert it in what i'm looking for ! 
Many thanks again guys!

Comment: Hello guys. This solution without method returns me an array with IDs and all the values I wanted in. I'm currently looking on SO if I could find a solution to get my output, but I found nothing. Any ideas ?